# Правильно зашифровать с помощью Base64

Tags: base64

Если зашифровать `PGh0bWw+DQo8aGVhZD4NCiAgICA8c3R5bGUgdHlwZT0idGV4dC9jc3MiPg0KICAgICAgICAueWlp` и `PGh0bWw+CjxoZWFkPgogICAgPHN0eWxlIHR5cGU9InRleHQvY3NzIj4KICAgICAgICAueWlp` то получится одинаковый результат

```
<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        .yii
```

А если расшифровать этот текст, то получится `PGh0bWw+CjxoZWFkPgogICAgPHN0eWxlIHR5cGU9InRleHQvY3NzIj4KICAgICAgICAueWlp`, а не `PGh0bWw+DQo8aGVhZD4NCiAgICA8c3R5bGUgdHlwZT0idGV4dC9jc3MiPg0KICAgICAgICAueWlp`. Почему так?

Answer (score 2):

В этих двух примерах различаются переводы строки. В первом - `\r\n` (новая строка в стиле Windows), во втором - `\n` (новая строка в стиле Unix):

```
$ python
Python 3.10.0 (default, Oct 16 2021, 12:17:56) [GCC 9.4.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
@>>> import base64
@>>> base64.b64decode("PGh0bWw+DQo8aGVhZD4NCiAgICA8c3R5bGUgdHlwZT0idGV4dC9jc3MiPg0KICAgICAgICAueWlp")
b'<html>\r\n<head>\r\n    <style type="text/css">\r\n        .yii'
@>>> base64.b64decode("PGh0bWw+CjxoZWFkPgogICAgPHN0eWxlIHR5cGU9InRleHQvY3NzIj4KICAgICAgICAueWlp")
b'<html>\n<head>\n    <style type="text/css">\n        .yii'
```

Не удивительно что вы не видите разницы в обычном редакторе или в консоли.

Answer (score 1):

в **linux** среде можно посмотреть так:

```
$ echo "PGh0bWw+DQo8aGVhZD4NCiAgICA8c3R5bGUgdHlwZT0idGV4dC9jc3MiPg0KICAgICAgICAueWlp" | base64 --decode | cat --show-ends
<html>^M$
<head>^M$
    <style type="text/css">^M$
        .yii
```

и

```
$ echo "PGh0bWw+CjxoZWFkPgogICAgPHN0eWxlIHR5cGU9InRleHQvY3NzIj4KICAgICAgICAueWlp" | base64 --decode | cat --show-ends
<html>$
<head>$
    <style type="text/css">$
        .yii
```

где `cat --show-ends` сделает для нас видимым символ перевода строки.

В первом варианте это `^M$`(\r\n) а во втором `$`(\n)

Подобное отображение перевода строки говорит о том что данный кусок кода скорее всего был преобразован в base64 на разных системах - **Windows** и **Linux** соответственно.

Чтобы избежать подобных проблем при переносе документов с одной платформы на другую в **linux** есть специальный инструмент `dos2unix` который преобразует документ и установит необходимые окончания строк, из примера выше:

```
$ echo "PGh0bWw+DQo8aGVhZD4NCiAgICA8c3R5bGUgdHlwZT0idGV4dC9jc3MiPg0KICAgICAgICAueWlp" | base64 --decode | dos2unix | cat --show-ends
<html>$
<head>$
    <style type="text/css">$
        .yii
```

утилиты `dos2unix` и `unix2dos` преобразуют документ в направлении соответствующем их названию. Также есть еще `unix2mac` и `mac2unix` с аналогичной функцией преобразования для **Linux** и **Mac**

п.с.

Возможно нужно будет доустановить пакет `dos2unix` который содержит в себе все вышеперечисленные утилиты для преобразования.